# Let $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be given by $ f(x) = x^2 -3$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Let $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be given by $ f(x) = x^2 -3$

Find $f([-2,1])$=   $[-3,1]$

Find $f^{-1}([-2,1])$= $[-1,1]$

I am not wonderful at these types of problems and I seem to make silly mistakes. Just want someone to double check my work.

Comment: Plot the parabola and then see the image and preimage of the given intervals.

Comment: your second answer is wrong, $f(0) = -3$ and $0 \in [-1,1]$ but $0 \not\in [-2,1]$

Answer (score 0):

To find $f([-2,1])$, you gotta find the maximum and minimum of $f$ on this interval.

As is obvious, $f(-2)=1$ is the maximum and $f(0)=-3$ is the minimum.

Thus, your answer $f([-2,1])=[-3,1]$ is correct.

As for the inverse, set

$x^2-3=y$

$x^2=y+3$

$x=\sqrt{y+3}$ or $x=-\sqrt{y+3}$

Technically, the function $f$ has no inverse, so we have to find the preimage.

Letting $y=-2$ then $y=1$ in the first we get,

$x\in[1,2]$ since it is strictly increasing as a function of $y$ there.

Letting $y=-2$ then $y=1$ in the second we get,

$x\in[-2,-1]$ since it is strictly decreasing there as a function of $y$.

Thus, $f^{-1}([-2;1])=[-2;-1]\cup[1;2]$